# How can I find the standard matrices of the linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> a) Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $T(u) = -u$. Find $T(u +v)$, then find $T(u) + T(v)$ and conclude that they are equal so that **i)** is satisfied. Then find $T(ru)$ and $rT(u)$  and conclude that they are equal so that **ii)** is satisfied. This shows $T$ is **linear**

**My Solution:**

**i)** $ T(u) = -u \implies T(u + v) = -u - v = (-u) + (-v) \implies T(u) + T(v) \checkmark$

**ii)** $T(ru) = -(ru) = (-ru) = r(-u) = rT(u) \checkmark$

> b)Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $T\begin{pmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}u_2\\0\\u_1-u_2\end{pmatrix}$
>
> Show T is linear.

**My Solution:**

Let $u = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

$T(u + v) = T((1+0), (0+1)) = T(1,1) = (1,0,0)$

$T(ru) = rT(u)?$

Let $u = 0$ so $T(0) = 0 \implies $ **Linear**

> c) Each linear transformation has a standard matrix. Find the standard matrices for the
> transformations in parts (a) and (b).

Yeah, I have no idea how to do this part.

Comment: Consider the transformation of the basis $\{e_j\}$ and the linearity of $T$. You can find the matrix related to $T$. Actually, each column of the matrix of $T$ is a transformed basis vector.

Comment: what is the *"transformation of the basis* $\{e_j\}$"? What is the *"transformed basis vector"* ?

Comment: Regarding part b): You have to check the two conditions for linearity for every two elements $(u_1, u_2), (v_1, v_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and not just $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner ?

Comment: @Yusha For example, $e_1=(1,0), e_2=(0,1)$ are the basis vectors of $R^2$. $T(e_1), T(e_2)$ are the transformed basis vectors, they form the columns of the matrix corresponding to $T$.

Comment: For example, if you get $x=a_1e_1+a_2e_2$, then $T(x)=a_1T(e_1)+a_2T(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix}T(e_1) T(e_2)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}$. So the matrix of $T$ is $\begin{bmatrix}T(e_1) T(e_2)\end{bmatrix}$. So, the key is to find the image of the basis.

Comment: Will you provide the answer to the three standard matrices? I am studying and want to see if I have done them correctly

Answer (score 1):

By standard matrix I suppose it means the matrix which represents $T$ in the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
This basis is, for $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\{ e_1 = (1,0), e_2 = (0,1)\}$.

So, to find the matrix representing a linear transformation on vector spaces you do

1. Apply $T$ on each vector of the basis
2. Form the matrix in which each column is the vector you got in (1).

For $T(u) = -u$.
Compute $T(e_1) = (-1,0)$ this is the first column of your standard matrix of $T$. Also compute $T(e_2) = (0,-1)$.

This yields to $-I$, in which $I$ is the identity matrix.

Do the same for $(b)$. Just be careful with the order you choose for the vector in the basis.

Comment: Will you provide the answer?  I am studying for something and want to make sure I have it correctly. As in , provide the 3 standard matrices